# ExtAudioFileWrite only writing the first bit of a file

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, audio

I'm using [ExtAudioFileWrite](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) to write from a MusicPlayer to a WAV file in an OSX project (using a Soundfont for the sound samples). It's embedded in a Rails app (using a Ruby extension to wrap up the Objective-C code), and this is running fine on my computer - the WAV file is written successfully.

However, I recently put the code up onto a Mac server so that I can access the app online. What I've found is that, when running on the server, the code produces a WAV file of the correct duration, but in which the audio from about 15 seconds in is completely silent.

It's as if ExtAudioFileWrite is continuing to write for the correct duration (the entire track), but, for some reason, after about 15 seconds of audio it starts writing silence.

Has anyone experienced this before?

This is the code that's doing the writing:

```
MusicTimeStamp currentTime;
AUOutputBL outputBuffer (clientFormat, numFrames);
AudioTimeStamp tStamp;
memset (&tStamp, 0, sizeof(AudioTimeStamp));
tStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
int i = 0;
int numTimesFor10Secs = (int)(10. / (numFrames / srate));

do {
    outputBuffer.Prepare();
    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags actionFlags = 0;
    FailIf ((result = AudioUnitRender (outputUnit, &actionFlags, &tStamp, 0, numFrames, outputBuffer.ABL())), fail, "AudioUnitRender");

    tStamp.mSampleTime += numFrames;

    ExtAudioFileWrite(outfile, numFrames, outputBuffer.ABL());

    MusicPlayerGetTime(player, &currentTime);
} while (currentTime < sequenceLength);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by making sure the server was running exactly the same OS and Xcode versions as were being run by my computer. This fixed the issue.